# How to add keyvault access policies after importing keyvault into terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice, azure-rm

My terraform design depends on a pre-provisioned keyvault containing secrets to be used by app services. I imported this key vault into my remote state. I can see it has been imported. Now when I run terraform plan, it acts as if it does not know about the imported resource.

This is how my terraform looks like

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version="=2.20.0"
    skip_provider_registration="true"  
    features{}
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {}
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                  = "${var.env}ActicoDQM-kv"
}

module "app_service_plan"{
  source                    = "./modules/app-service-plan"
 ...redacted for brevity
  tags                      = var.tags
}

module "app-service"{
  source                = "./modules/app-service"
...redacted for brevity
  tags                  = var.tags
  key_vault_id          = azurerm_key_vault.kv.key_vault_id
}
```

Adding an access policy for the app service  inside the module

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app" {
... redacted for brevity 
  }

  identity {
      type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "app" {
  key_vault_id       = var.key_vault_id
  tenant_id          = azurerm_app_service.app.identity[0].tenant_id
  object_id          = azurerm_app_service.app.identity[0].principal_id
  secret_permissions = ["get", "list"]
}
```

There seems to be some missing link in my understanding, because now when I do

```
terraform plan
```

It acts as if it doesn't know about imported keyvault

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on main.tf line 19, in resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv":
  19: resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {

The argument "tenant_id" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're importing an existing keyvault into your terraform state you need to fully define all required arguments according to [keyvault resource docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/key_vault.html).

At minimum your keyvault resource should specify these arguments:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                  = "${var.env}ActicoDQM-kv"
  location              = ..
  resource_group_name   = ..
  sku_name              = "standard" or "premium"
  tenant_id             = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
}
```

You can expose the tenant_id using a data resource:

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about needing any minimum fields in spite of import. But it worked. Thank You!

Comment: I get it now, the resource block must have all the fields required to create the resource, so that the script is complete even without import. Took a little experience with destroying and applying to get the complete picture.